# How can I add a login page to the charisma bundle

Tags: laravel, charisma

I am using the great charima bundle to the `laravel framework 3.2`.

How can I add a login page to the `/admin` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charisma is not an administration panel in itself. It is simply a user-interface (or theme, whichever you prefer) that you can use for your own administration panel. You will need to build your own panel that makes use of it.

Please consider looking at the [Laravel Auth Usage Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/auth/usage) for further information on using authentication and protecting your admin route.

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', function() {}));
```